# What is the behavior of `command`?

Tags: shell-script, shell-builtin

According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script#comment80859618_26759734) which is in defense of the author's answer,

> @einpoklum Yes, it is necessary. In fact, even this solution may break in one edge case. **Thanks for bringing this to my attention. `dash`, `bash`, and `zsh` all skip over non-executable files in `$PATH` when executing a command. However, the behavior of `command -v` is very inconsistent. In dash, it returns the first matching file in `$PATH`, regardless of whether it's executable or not. In bash, it returns the first executable match in `$PATH`, but if there's none, it can return a non-executable file. And in `zsh`, it will never return a non-executable file.** – nyuszika7h Oct 26 at 13:52

Is this documented anywhere but in this question? Is the behavior of `command` spec'ed anywhere?

Trying with bash, I can't see it returning a non-executable file. I've tried.

Comment: You may want to look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/38906

Comment: @cuonglm wow, it's a shame that history lesson/book isn't split across 5 more appropriately titled quesitons. But, yeah, that has 100% of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, here's the spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html